# Pytest-mock and unittest mock

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm new to Python and recently, I've seen that since Python 3.3, if I'm not mistaken, unittest is the standard testing framework.

I'm working on a project that uses Pytest with the pytest-mock plugin. Reading the plugin documentation, I saw that it is a thin wrapper of unittest mock, and the patch API is the same.
So my question is, why to use pytest-mock plugin instead of avoid adding one more dependency to your project and just go with unittest mock?

I tried reading the documentation for both, unittest and pytest / pytest-mock, but I can't seem to find arguments that would justify using pytest-mock if I could just use the standard unittest.

Comment: `pytest-mock` makes the usage of `mock` in `pytest` a bit more convenient, and more in line with the `pytest`  style, but in the end you can use `unittest.mock` directly without problems (I do so myself). A common idiom is to write your own fixtures for mocks that may use `mock` directly, while the tests will just use these fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888992/what-are-the-differences-between-unittest-mock-mock-mocker-and-pytest-mock#:%7E:text=pytest%2Dmock%20is%20a%20pytest,test%20teardown%2C%20ensuring%20test%20isolation.), but personally I would use `pytest-mock` plugin, it's better in

1. Making the code look cleaner
2. More readable
3. Is more powerful
4. Easier to test targets with no return values
   And so on.